# data.table manipulation in R environment

Tags: r, data.table

I'm handling fairly heavily environments in R lately and I found `data.table` not to behave reliably when enclosed in environments (passed to functions etc...). I typically get the error:

> Error in `:=`(d, 4) :    Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE.
>   Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in
>   particular ways. See help(":=").

Surprisingly this happens on some computers and not others, though they have very similar setup (ubuntu, same version of R, same version of data.table, ...)

Hereafter a minimal example to get this error, on any computer I have access to. Could anybody explain why such an error occur in this minimal case:

```
library("data.table")
dat <- data.frame(c=c(1,2),b=c(3,4))
datDT <- data.table(dat)
datDT[,d:=4]
my.env <- new.env()
assign("datDT",my.env)
my.env$datDT[,d:=4]
```

Of course guesses about the more specific problem of having just the first four lines fail in some functions, but only on some computers would be welcome!

Comment: Um, `str(my.env$datDT) # NULL` Guess you bugged out somewhere in your process. Like maybe you didn't pass the arguments to `assign` correctly. Try getting into the habit of passing by name instead of by position to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by Frank the issue was by incorrect usage of `assign` function. Below code will address your case.

```
library("data.table")
dat <- data.frame(c=c(1,2),b=c(3,4))
datDT <- data.table(dat)
datDT[,d:=4]
my.env <- new.env()
assign("datDT", datDT, envir = my.env)
my.env$datDT[,d:=4]
my.env$datDT[]
#   c b d
#1: 1 3 4
#2: 2 4 4
```